# Rewrite and interpret such an equation

Tags: integration

Could someone explain how this equation (2) can be rewritten in the way it has been done? Furthermore, it is said that differentiating the left side of equation (2) with respect to $n$ has the same sign as $f'$, apparently this can be derived from equation (3) but I do not see that.

[image: Find the equations here]

Comment: I need the equation before the one listed (and perhaps the one before that).

Comment: I added the equations directly before the ones listed. Hope that helps

Comment: Bro, it'd be much better if they were all on the same document.  I could do it, but I don't really want to.

Comment: I've put them on the same document. I'd appreciate it if you could give it a try, you would help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's call the equation after (2) equation (2.5).  With equation (2.5), we see that
$$\int_{-a}^a (n-1)f^2 F^{n-2} d\epsilon = f(a)-\int_{-a}^a F^{n-1} f' d\epsilon. $$
We now want to take the derivative of the left side of equation (2.5) with respect to $n$.  Which is equivalent to taking the derivative of the right side of equation (2.5) with respect to $n$.  That is,
$$\frac{d}{dn}\int_{-a}^a (n-1)f^2 F^{n-2} d\epsilon = \frac{d}{dn}\left( f(a)-\int_{-a}^a F^{n-1} f' d\epsilon \right). $$
Distributing the derivative, we get
$$\frac{d}{dn}\int_{-a}^a (n-1)f^2 F^{n-2} d\epsilon = \frac{d}{dn} f(a) -
 \frac{d}{dn} \int_{-a}^a F^{n-1} f' d\epsilon. $$
With respect to $n$, $f(a)$ is a constant, so $\frac{d}{dn} f(a)=0$.  That leaves us with
$$-\frac{d}{dn} \int_{-a}^a F^{n-1} f' d\epsilon. $$
Recall that $\frac{d}{dx} a ^x = \ln a \, a^x$ (you can see an explanation as to why here: https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-integrate-3-x).  Using this formula on the above expression, we get:
$$\frac{d}{dn}\int_{-a}^a (n-1)f^2 F^{n-2} d\epsilon = \int_{-a}^a -\left(\ln F \right), F^{n-1} f'\,d\epsilon. $$

Comment: Thanks a lot so far. Could you also explain how equation (2.5) is derived from equation (2)?

Comment: @Andy Equation (2.5) is not derived from equation (2).  Instead, the left side of equation (2.5) is a part of equation (2).  It's the term involving the integral without the $W_1-W_2$, and they took out the epsilons.

Comment: Then I phrased it incorrectly. How do they transform the part of left-side of equation (2) so that it can be written as on the right-hand side of equation (2.5).

Comment: @Andy I think you need to apply integration by parts twice.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll give it a try